# Extending the Page Model in django-cms 3.01

Tags: django, django-cms

I just started using django-cms 3.01 and django 1.6.4/python 2.7.6. My last experience with django was 1.4 and I've never used django-cms before now.

I am trying to follow the instructions in the official documentation on [Extending the Page & Title Models](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending_cms/extending_page_title.html), but I am experiencing an issue.

The custom field I need to add is very similar to the example, so I simply used their code exactly. Rand a syncdb, started the server and everything was going well. The  field shows in the admin just fine. There is an entry in the admin menu for "Icon Extensions." I click add, and I get to the form to upload the file. I go to upload the file, and I receive the following error:

```
DoesNotExist at /admin/the_site_name/iconextension/add/
IconExtension has no extended_object.
...
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    IconExtension has no extended_object.
Exception Location: /Users/me/Sites/the_site_name/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py in __get__, line 326
```

Most likely I'm just missing something simple, but I can't figure it out. Should I have a foreignkey linking it directly to the page? I thought it was handled automatically, but obviously I'm not completely getting it jsut yet.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must edit extensions in the frontend editing toolbar. Add a button to toolbar as described in the section "Adding a Toolbar Menu Item for your Page extension" in the documentation you linked above.

Comment: I'm trying the same tutorial, and @Tim suggested and according to tutorial i also added a cms_toolbar.py to the app, but same error is thrown. As the tutorial says each extension must be related to a particular page object. And when an extension object is saved, no related page object is found to be associated with this. hence the error. but how to fix the error.

Comment: You must edit extensions in the frontend editing toolbar (appears when you append '?edit' to the page's URL), not in the admin interface. There is no way to associate a page with an extension in the admin.